# React Router DOM v6 alternative for this.props.match.params, prevProps.match.params, this.props.location.pathname, prevProps.location.pathname

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I have previously used React Router DOM v4 and the following:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if ((prevProps.match.params[0] !== this.props.match.params[0])) {
        ...some code
    }
}

componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
    if (this.props.location.pathname !== prevProps.location.pathname){
        this.loadContent();
    }
}
```

how should I replace them in the v6?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `useEffect` hook with dependency to replace `componentDidUpdate` and the `useLocation` and `useParams` hooks to replace the `location` and `match` props.

Example:

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useLocation, useParams } from 'react-router-dom';

...

const{ pathname } = useLocation();
const {/* destructured param */} = useParams();

useEffect(() => {
  loadContent();
}, [pathname]);

useEffect(() => {
  ...some code
}, [/* destructured param */]);
```

If your question is really about how to use the `react-router-dom@6` hooks with an older class component, then you'll need to create a custom Higher Order Component to use the hooks and inject the props.

Example:

```
import {
  useLocation,
  useParams,
  /* other hooks */
} from 'react-router-dom';

const withRouter = Component => props => {
  const location = useLocation();
  const params = useParams();
  // other hooks

  return (
    <Component
      {...props}
      {...{ location, params, /* other hook props */ }}
    />
  );
};

export default withRouter;
```

Then you can decorate your class component and use the `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle methods and access `this.props.location` and `this.props.params`. *Note that there isn't a `match` prop now, e.g. `this.props.match.params` is now just `this.props.params`.*